# xslt get parent element by another element value

Tags: xml, xslt

Im trying to get the parent node based of child element value

I want to do  something like that  **get TransactionDetail element  where SequenceNumber = 2**

I tried to do it like that  but im missing something...

```
 ancestor:://*[local-name()='SequenceNumber'][text()=2]

 //TransactionDetail[//SequenceNumber = 2]
```

this is the xml

```
<Root>
<biztalk_1>

    <body>
        <ActiveStore_SalesTransaction_1.70>

            <TransactionDetail>
                <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber>

                <TransactionDetailGroup>
                    <Item>
                        <ItemID>22</ItemID>

                        <NonMerchandiseFlag>1</NonMerchandiseFlag>
                    </Item>
                </TransactionDetailGroup>
            </TransactionDetail>




        </ActiveStore_SalesTransaction_1.70>
    </body>
</biztalk_1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `name()` is not a good practice. Instead, use the element name in the xpath as below:

```
//TransactionDetail[SequenceNumber = 2]
```

The xpath selects all the `TransactionDetail` elements with a child `SequenceNumber` with value `2` in the whole document.

And if you want `TransactionDetail` with any descendant `SequenceNumber` with value `2`, use:

```
//TransactionDetail[.//SequenceNumber = 2]
```

Here, the `.//SequenceNumber` makes sure that only the current `TransactionDetail`'s descendant `SequenceNumber` elements are checked.

Comment: @MIkCode There could be many reasons for this. I'm pointing some here. 1. The processing is much faster(depending of the processor). Some processors may list all the descendants first (because of `*`), and then filter based on `name()`. 2. The Xpath is easy to write without `name()`. Moreover, there is no necessity for using `name()` in such xpaths unless you want to escape the namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="Root">
    <Root>
        <xsl:copy-of select="descendant::*[name()='TransactionDetail']
                                                        [descendant::*[name()='SequenceNumber']='2']"/>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```